# How to append text files using batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I append file1 to file2, from a batch file?
Text files and only using what is "standard" on windows.

Comment: `copy *.txt output.dat`, I  got to read across this today. Thought of posting here. This will copies and appends all the `*.txt` file into single `.dat` file.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It is as simple as

```
type file1 >> file2
```

Comment: the `type` command does `echo` all contents of `file1` and `>>` will append it to `file2`

Comment: Can be an issue using this with first line of second file on same line as last line of prev file.     e.g. an SQL file ending in GO and an SQL file starting with GO I get GOGO on one line ..  I will try appending a file containing just one empty line between all the other appends to get around this issue .. looks like Stephan commented same with answer below also.

Comment: I'd argue that this is the correct behavior. A file is a sequence of bytes, whether or not the bytes are assumed to be encode text, or machine code, or images, or videos. Bytes are just bytes. Appending files is just appending two byte streams. If the `>>` operator were defined to automatically insert bytes representing a newline (and what encoding would you choose? which code points would you choose?) that would be wrong. Now if your intent is to automatically insert newlines at the ends of files that don't have them, you are correct, it is the programmer's responsibility!

Answer (score 11):

You *might* get better results with the following:

```
copy /b file1.txt+file2.txt result.txt
```

I use this command to combine dozens of XML files together.  The "/b" puts the copy process in binary mode.  This eliminated the control character that was appending to the end of my destination file.

Comment: if the last line of `file1` does not end with a line feed (that's quite common with textfiles), the first line of `file2` will be added to the last line of 'file1`

Comment: This result also has `file1` and `file2` reversed from what the OP requested.  Also, in case it matters to anyone, note that with this method (unlike when using `>>` in another answer) the result file does not retain the same NTFS file identifier ("frn") as the file that was appended to, but rather gets a new file ID.

Answer (score 6):

```
COPY file1.txt+file2.txt result.txt
```

Comment: This result has `file1` and `file2`reversed from what the OP requested.

Comment: @GlennSlayden - so it is, 8 years and nobody else seems to have noticed! I wonder whether OP could figure it out.