# Out of python to .txt file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a batch script runs  python script continuously in a loop.

```
:start
python log_capture.py > log.txt
goto start
```

I want to print the output of each iteration in a .txt file. I am using following command get output from log_capture.py to a log.txt file.

```
python log_capture.py >log.txt
```

But in the next loop, the logs from previous iteration is overwritten. How can I prevent log.txt file being overwritten or lets say save output from each iteration in different log.txt file

Comment: Why not have the python script create/write the file? Then you could dynamically create the file name in the script.

Comment: Have you tried a `for` in bash?

Comment: just change it from `> log.txt` to `>> log.txt` to append.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append text files using batch files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750653/how-to-append-text-files-using-batch-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `>>` instead of `>` to append to a file instead of overwriting it.

`python log_capture.py >> log.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Using `>>`, as suggested by evsheino, is correct for appending to the file. If you want a separate log file for each loop, create a counter variable and use it in the log file name.

```
SET /A COUNTER=0
:DoOver
python -c "print 'hello, world'" >"python_logfile_%COUNTER%.txt"
SET /A COUNTER+=1
GOTO DoOver
```

NB: I would not use a program name like `start` as a label. It is probably no problem, but who knows?