# How to merge multiple .csv in a folder using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge, concatenation

I have a folder with 12 .csv files which I wish to merge row by row.

This is the code I have to load one of the .csv

## Code

```py
test = pd.read_csv("D:\DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201612.csv", header=None, names=['Date', 'sell_A', 'buy_A', 'unknown'], parse_dates=["Date"])
```

How would I merge all 12 which have the names shown below (current one is 201612);

DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201601.csv
DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201602.csv
DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201603.csv
DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201604.csv
DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201605.csv
DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201606.csv
DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201607.csv
DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201608.csv
DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201609.csv
DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201610.csv
DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201611.csv
DAT_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201612.csv

Comment: you could append of the files together without python, no ?
or do you want to do it with python to train yourself ?

Comment: Partially to train myself but if there is a simple way not through python them open to suggestions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969641/how-to-append-one-file-to-another-in-linux-from-the-shell

Comment: on windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750653/how-to-append-text-files-using-batch-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do using [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

# set your file path
pt = Path("your_file_path/")

name = ['Date', 'sell_A', 'buy_A', 'unknown']
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=name, parse_dates=["Date"]) for file in pt.glob("*.csv")])
```